# What is the Default Product Image dimension on Magento?

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.3, product-edit

I have tried to upload the product image with the dimension 2000 x 2000 but in the admin panel it showing the image dimension is 1200 x 1200 though I uploaded the image with 2000 x 2000. So my doubt is, what is the Default Product Image dimension on Magento?

**Version: Magento 2.2.3**

Please comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail : 50 x 50 pixels

Small Image : 470 x 470 pixels

Base Image  : 470 x 470 pixels (without Zoom)
              1100 x 1100 pixels (with Zoom)

Comment: However, I have checked and see the path "vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php", that says below

/**
     * Max Image Width resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
     */
    const MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1920;

    /**
     * Max Image Height resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
     */
    const MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1200;

If possible, could you please clarify about this?